# Why did the pensieve show Harry the trial of Igor Karkaroff?

Tags: harry-potter

In Goblet of Fire, book & film, why did the pensieve show Harry the particular memory of Igor Karkaroff's trial?

Usually, to be observed, a particular memory has to be poured into the pensieve?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Dumbledore was already viewing that particular memory and didn't put his thought away, thinking that he could simply return to it after his guests had left.

> *‘A connection I could have made without assistance,’ Dumbledore
> sighed, ‘but never mind.’ He peered over the top of his half-moon
> spectacles at Harry, who was gaping at Snape’s face, which was
> continuing to swirl around the bowl. **‘I was using the Pensieve when Mr
> Fudge arrived for our meeting, and put it away rather hastily.**
> Undoubtedly I did not fasten the cabinet door properly. Naturally, it
> would have attracted your attention.’*
>
> <sub><sup>CHAPTER THIRTY — The Pensieve</sup></sub>